# Alternative to weight-paint and mesh deform rigging?

Tags: animation, rigging, armature, weight-painting

I'm seeking to evolve from my current and very problematic workflow of using weight-painting to deform meshes. Things usually deform strangely and getting any sort of elegant 'knee bend' or similar body movement awkward, usually giving **shrinking deformations** I do not want. Problems compound when I try to involve clothes - shrinking, unwanted intersection, etc.

Bending our real-life knee is simple - our skin is wrapped around the bone. One would think this should be easy in 3d? Yet I'm not sure which workflow simulates this. The same principle would be with clothing around the flesh.

**Is there a more sophisticated rigging method that is more intuitive?**